# Quais as vantagens em usar a propriedade box-sizing em elementos?

Tags: css, front-end

Gostaria de saber quais as vantagens da propriedade box-sizing do CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para facilitar seu entendimento eu criei esse arquivo .html com um esclarecimento simples e agradável de sua dúvida.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#exemplo1 {
    box-sizing: content-box;    
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;    
    border: 10px solid black;
}

#exemplo2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px;    
    border: 10px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>A propriedade css: box-sizing </h1>
<p>Define como a largura e a altura de um elemento são calculadas: devem incluir preenchimento e bordas ou não.</p>

<h2>box-sizing: content-box (padrão):</h2>
<p>Largura e altura só se aplicam ao conteúdo do elemento, aqui as propriedades de largura e tamanho da div não serão limitadas pelo box-sizing</p>
<div id="exemplo1">A div irá manter suas propriedades e a largura da borda irá somar com o tamanho total da div. width 300px + padding 30px + border 10px</div>

<h2>box-sizing: border-box:</h2>
<p>Largura e altura se aplicam para as partes do elemento, ou seja, a borda fará parte do tamanho total da div, tanto como a borda e o padding.</p>
<div id="exemplo2">Aqui, a largura total é 300 px.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Anexo]
*O Anexo acima é referente ao código explicativo citado inicialmente.*

**Nota**: Basta você copiar o código da *amostra de código* acima e salvar em um arquivo com a extensão html. Exemplo: **index.html**.

Espero ter ajudado.